# SnapTag reader SDK for iOS

Tags: ios5, qr-code, ios6.1, scannable-code

I checked everywhere for SnapTag SDK for iOS, but there is no luck. Is there any integration package for scanning SnapTag on iOS ?

Comment: I believe you have to establish a relationship with them in order to get the SDK